# OrderBy List by another collection

Tags: c#

Have some problem.
Need to sort the list by another collection:

```
List<Books> b = new List<Books>();
```

Class Books:

```
public partial class Books
{
    public Books()
    {
        this.BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthors>();
    }

    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthors> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

Class BookAuthors:

```
public partial class BookAuthors
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public virtual Books Books { get; set; }
    public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Class Authors:

```
public partial class Authors
{
    public Authors()
    {
        this.BookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthors>();
    }

    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookAuthors> BookAuthors { get; set; }
}
```

How i can sort b by authors last name?

Comment: What did you try at the moment?

Comment: You need to give it a go I am afraid :)

Comment: What collection do you want to sort?

Comment: _How i can sort this by authors last name?_ => given you are allowing n authors per book what should be taken as the author for sorting, the first author in the list, the author with the alphabetically sorted 1st last name....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, though with mutiple authors it remains a question which author you order by:

```
var sorted = 
    from book in b
    let firstAuthor = book.BookAuthors.First()
    let lastName = firstAuthor.LastName
    order book by lastName 
    select book
```

Alternatively you could apply some logic (if you had it)...

```
var sorted = 
    from book in b
    let author = book.BookAuthors.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Primary) ?? 
        book.BookAuthors.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Editor) ??
        book.BookAuthors.First()
    let lastName = author.LastName
    order book by lastName 
    select book
```